# In Nimrod, what is the syntax for bitwise operations?

Tags: bitwise-operators, nim-lang

I'm just discovering Nimrod and have a basic question (couldn't find the answer in the documentation).

How do you use bitwise operations ? I have the following code, where x is defined as an int :

```
if x and 1:
```

This does not compile :

```
Error: type mismatch: got (range 0..1(int)) but expected 'bool'
```

And if I try:

```
if and(x, 1)
```

I get

```
Error: type mismatch: got (tuple[int, int])
but expected one of:  
system.and(x: int16, y: int16): int16
system.and(x: int64, y: int64): int64
system.and(x: int32, y: int32): int32
system.and(x: int, y: int): int
system.and(x: bool, y: bool): bool
system.and(x: int8, y: int8): int8
```

What's the trick ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`and` does bitwise and; the issue is rather that `if` expects a `bool`, not an integer. If you want C-like comparison to 0, simply add it:

```
>>> if 1:
...   echo("hello")
...
stdin(10, 4) Error: type mismatch: got (int literal(1)) but expected 'bool'
>>> if 1!=0:
...   echo("hello")
...
hello
```

Comment: No, I really need to perform a bitwise-and on my variable ; more precisely, here, I want to check whether the last bit is set or not.

Comment: So use `(x and 1) != 0`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the last bit you can use **testBit** from the [bitops](https://nim-lang.org/docs/bitops.html#testBit%2CT%2CBitsRange%5BT%3A+SomeInteger%5D) module:

```
import bitops
if testBit(x, 0):
  echo "Last bit is 1"
```